# Out of Memory Error while training model using Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, gpu

I've been training a model using just tensorflow on my GPU with the help of `tf.device()`, it was working fine until now. I am making another NN model in Keras and while using `model.fit` it is giving me OOM error.

Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

OOM(Out of memory) error comes when your model want to use more memory then available memory. Check your GPU memory whether memory is occupied by some process before training. In nvidia GPU you can check with memory by command `nvidia-smi` in cmd before starting the training.

If no memory is occupied by any process or model before starting of training and you still getting OOM error then you have to optimize your model by Changing batch size or reducing data size or image size or by reducing trainable parameters of model(number of neurons).

Comment: I'll try that and let you know in 24 hours if  it solves my problem, thank you for the solution. :)

Comment: here it shows that "nvidia-smi is not recognized as a command", what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now. I switched to google.colab for a while, but after sometime, i used it on my  device and it ran perfectly, i did cleaned up some files in between, and was experimenting with my GPU, i guess something in  that triggered the solution. Thank You anyway.